# Have I completed installation? no wifi reconized... connected via ethernet

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04, broadcom

I am new to Linux. I am using it for only 24 hours. I have never used it before, and never installed it before. But I want to learn it.

I have Powerbook g4, 1.5ghz. I tried to install "Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS" on it with the "minimal CD" and I wonder if I am missing something. There are many issues. I think there is something major I am missing.

I am unable to connect to any WiFi network. The WiFi networks are not present .

I have got an Ethernet cord plugged into the machine to get online. When I click on the connections button on top, it says `No valid active connections found` (should it recognize the ethernet connection here?)

I have the Broadcom BCM4306 802.11b/g Wireless controller on my machine.

Do I have to manually install a driver to get my wireless to function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)